# Derive template type of derived class from base class pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Consider the following:

1. a class *B*
2. a class *D*, which

   - is derived from class *B*,
   - has a template parameter *T*,
   - has a member variable *x* of type *T*
3. a template function *F* with

   - a template parameter *S*
   - a parameter y of type *S*.
4. a pointer *p*, which

   - has the type *B* *
   - is pointing to an object *o* of class *D* with the template parameter *T* equal to e.g. *int*
5. that the function *F* cannot be modfied.
6. F cannot be invoked directly from classes B or D

Consider furthermore that only the pointer *p* is given and that *F* should be called with parameter *y* equal to the member variable *x* of object *o* (this means with the type *S* equal to *int*).

How can classes *B* and *D* be modfied to achieve this? I guess some kind of mechanism to derive the template type *T* is required. But I don't know how to do that.

Here is the related code:

File F.h:

```
#include <iostream>
//////////// Consider that the lines up to the next comment cannot be changed
template< typename S > void F( S y )
{
    std::cout << y <<  " of some type" << std::endl; 
}

template<> void F<>( int y )
{
    std::cout << y << " of int type." << std::endl; 
}
//////////// -----------------------------
```

File BD.h:

```
// F.h cannot be included here
class B { };

template<typename T> class D : public B { public:  T x;  };
```

File main.cpp:

```
#include "BD.h"
#include "F.h"
int main()
{
    D<int>  o;
    o.x  =  3;
    B* p = &o;

    // Obviously, the following line will not work:
    // F( p->x );

    // Obviously, the following will work:
    F( ( (D<int>*) p)->x );

    // However, consider that 
    //   1) only p is given and
    //   2) that it is not known that p points to an object of type D<int>.
    // How to modify B or D to be able to invoke the correct instantiation of F here
    // , i.e. that for the type of "int"?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to narrow the desciption to the core problem. Actually, I want to have an array or vector of pointer of type `B`, such that I can access or handle objects of class D with different template parameters T jointly, e.g. by further extending `B`s interface (maybe even with virtual functions).

Comment: Why can't F.h be included? This sounds like an X-Y problem, and the solution might be to work around that limitation instead. (Maybe `F` can be forward declared?)

Comment: Can `B` know each *"possible"* derived `class D<T>` ?

Comment: BTW, you should avoid to edit your question in a way which invalidate existing answers. (You may ask another for example).

Comment: @aschepler: First, for practical reasons as I'm running in dependency issues in the (large) project I'm working on. This might be solved, however, the effort for this is unclear.  Second, also for conceputal reasons as it should be possible to use BD.h in other projects without having F.h.

Comment: @Jarod42. Sorry for the edit. I'm new here and considered this as clarificaiton. It won't happen again. Considering, `B`, it can know each possible derived `class D<T>`

Comment: So [Visitor_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can help.

Answer (score 1):

You might do

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class D : public B
{
public:
    void f() const override { F(x); }
private:
    T x;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/EtbSmd)

Comment: This would be a solution given how the first version of the question is posed. However, I have the problem that the declaration/definition of F is not available when D and B are defined. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback along with a virtual member function to call it:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void call() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class D : public B
{
public:
    explicit D(T t, std::function<void(T)> cb)
        : x(std::move(t)),
          callback(std::move(cb))
    {
    }
    void call() const override
    {
        callback(x);
    }
private:
    T x;
    std::function<void(T)> callback;
};

int main()
{
    D<int> o(3, F<int>);
    B* p = &o;
    p->call();
)
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6adaf404fb20e334)